Rename vertex_group in all associated modifiers
The mesh contains different Vertex Groups.
There are many objects that use the same Mesh.
Moreover, these objects have Mask modifiers that show only a specific Vertex Group.
If you rename Vertex Group, the name will change in Mesh Data, but in all modifiers it will remain the same! And there you will need to change it manually.
On the contrary, if Object data-block is used in some modifier, then when renaming Object, the name will be changed everywhere automatically.
How can I achieve the same behavior for Vertex Group?
Perhaps there is some kind of addon?
Thank you in advance.
